# How to sync when you can't connect directly to the remote computer

Tags: linux, ssh, portforwarding, unison

I have my home computer A and a work computer C that I want to synchronise using unison.  In the middle is a work computer B. A can communicate with B and B can communicate with C directly but A and C can't directly connect to each other.   In fact the communication diagram looks like A->B<->C. That is A can connect to B but B can't connect to A.

To give an example how I use this setup, I currently do the following if I want to ssh from A to C

ssh -t -X -C me_B@B ssh -X me_C@C

How can I run unison from A and sync with C, maybe using ssh port forwarding?

To make it a little clearer, C has unfiltered outgoing connectivity to the Internet. B has unfiltered in and outgoing connectivity to both C and the Internet. A is my home computer.

---

**Update**

The following command line works for me to at least copy files from A to C

```
scp -oProxyCommand="ssh me_B@B nc -v %h %p" foo/* me_C@C:foo
```

Is there some way to use this idea to get unison to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ssh port forwarding can be used for that. Use the following command on A if you want to forward ssh on port 22 at C to the local port 3000 (for example):

```
# Create the tunnel
ssh -L 3000:C:22 userB@B -N
```

After you have issued the command, you can login into C from A using:

```
# Connect using the tunnel
ssh -p 3000 userC@localhost
```

**Note:** During the discussion below it turned out, that in OP's network, the connection trough the tunnel can only be established using the following command:

```
ssh -p 3000 -l userC localhost
```

Note that I'm using `-l userC` instead of `userC@`.

---

Now you can use `unison` like this:

```
unison directory ssh://userC@localhost:3000 directory
```

Comment: What the unison command line look like? Something like `unison  directory ssh://me_B@localhost directory` ?

Comment: Let us test it step by step. Can you ssh connect to C from A using the commands I provided?

Comment: I run ssh -L 3000:C:22 userB@B -N in one window and it asks for the password for B which I enter.  I then do ssh -p 3000 userC@localhost from another and I see `channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed` in the first window. The second window just shows `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: Then port forwarding is prohibited by the administrators of `B`. No chance.

Comment: How come `ssh -t -X -C me_B@B ssh -X me_C@C` works and can I do something similar for unison?

Comment: I would suggest to report this problem to your administrators at work. Maybe they will allow forwarding to C if it is helpful. I don't see a chance afar from that.

Comment: Is there something called a "reverse ssh tunnel" that might work?

Comment: Can you reach A from C without B?

Comment: Yes in theory. A is my home computer so you can't actually ssh into it from anywhere as it doesn't run an ssh server.  But C has free outgoing access to the Internet. It's just incoming traffic that is blocked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63358/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-user2179021).

Comment: I added an update to the question. Maybe nc can help?

Comment: I worked out why it wasn't working! Something really dim. `ssh -N -f -L 2025:C:22 me_B@B` then `ssh -p 2025 -l me_C localhost` works. If you use me_C@ instead it fails with the error message I gave you.  If you could update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: strange!! I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Just add that the question is really clear and the current answer works perfectly for me.